# Can I use the Grails session to store entire domain objects?

Tags: performance, session, object, grails, dns

If I have a number of Grails domain objects that I do not want to save just yet, but still access them throughout my application, is it wise to store them in the Grails / Hibernate session (especially as regards peformance)? If not, what is the alternative?

Comment: imitate the same domainClass as a src/groovy/ class {bean} and reuse it that way then when ready just use that bean i.e.  new domain(bean). Alternatively refer to grails transactions roll back https://github.com/vahidhedayati/test-transactions goes into it a little bit where you roll back multiple objects if something fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you mean by *the grails / hibernate session*?

If you really mean the Hibernate session, adding an object to it will provoke the object to be saved automatically when the session is flushed (unless the object doesn't validate, in that case it will be lost once the session is discarded). A session is created and discared per request.

If you mean the `session` object that gets automatically injected into controllers and views, it's nor grails neither Hibernate specific, but just the old, plain HttpSession from the Servlet specification (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

You can use that to store any kind of object if you need to access them **across multiple requests of the same client**. Meaning the session is private to a given client (who identifies it throught the jsessionid cookie) and survives multiple requests. If you don't need the multiple request bit, adding them as a request attribute would suffice.

Putting things in the session is generally fine and fast (since by default is based on memory), but it will increase the memory footprint of the application if abused, and will prevent horizontal scaling (i.e deploying the same application in multiple instances) unless sticky session mechanisms are used (or the session is persisted).

Bear in mind though that grails uses a new Hibernate session per request (not an Http session :), so if you add objects that are attached to a Hibernate session to the Http session, and then the Hibernate session is closed, you might encounter problems. This shouldn't affect non-saved objects (they don't come from a Hibernate session), but it might affect their associations (other domain classes that do come from the database and therefore a Hibernate session). If that's the case, you might need to re-attach them. See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/attach.html

Also, if the session is invalidated (because the user logs out, or the server is re-deployed) everything that was stored in there will be gone.

If you don't want to rely on sessions at all, you can create your own a `MemoryBasedStoreService` service and use a `ConcurrentHashMap` or a similar mechanism to store and retrieve the objects. Since services are singleton in Grails, you can use it across the whole application, regardless of requests or clients - as long as your application is deployed in a single instance of course :).

Comment: Thank you very much! Better of an answer than I could have hoped for :)